# Split log file by time range

Tags: sed, awk, logs, cut

I have a log file and would like to cut it into copies of 15min.  In the log file the lines start with:

```
dd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss,xxx
```

e.g.

```
12 Feb 2013 16:05:02,xxx log text...
```

and the file rotates every hour so I would like to take a copy of the log file, split it into  15min of logging and have say 4 log files.

Comment: cut doesn't support completely regexr , So use awk.Also cut have probelm with space.awk solved it.

Comment: You might check [cronosplit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/cronosplit.1m.html) to split the files out.

Comment: For obvious reasons, being able to split into 20-minute pieces would make this a lot easier. (In case that 15-minutes requirement isn't set in stone.)

Comment: A regex for grep could select a range of time from a log. But you will have to adjust it for each time range, for each day. Scripting this would give you more iterative control over the lines you process. Let me suggest Python.

Answer (score 2):

If the lines all are correctly formatted, then

```
awk -F: '{print >int($2/15)*15 ".log"}' inputfile
```

will produce file 0.log, 15.log, 30.log and 45.log.

It works by splitting using colon as the delimiter, so the second field of `dd mm yyyy hh:mm:ss,xxx` is `mm`. We divide this by 15, take the integer part, and multiply by 15 to get `mm` value at the start of the quarter hour. We then append the string `".log"`. We then tell awk to print the current line to that file.

Answer (score 1):

AWK:

```
cat input |
    awk -F ':' '{if ($2 < 15) {print $0 > "15.log"} else print}' |
    awk -F ':' '{if ($2 < 30) {print $0 > "30.log"} else print}' |
    awk -F ':' '{if ($2 < 45) {print $0 > "45.log"} else print}' |
    cat > 60.log
```